# Maximal sum of unique vertices' weights in a grap

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic

I'm given a directed graph with weights assigned to vertices, not edges. My goal is to find the maximal weight of a path in this graph. A path's weight is a sum of weights of all *unique* vertices it contains. A vertex may be visited multiple times on a path, though it counts only once.

Cycles may and probably will be present.

Weights are positive integers.

Reconstructing the path isn't necessary.

Because of the size of the graph, it cannot be represented as adjacency matrix (this may have an impact on the time complexity).

The graph doesn't have to be neither strongly nor weakly connected.

Example:

`1 -> 20 -> 5
A    |
|   \/
14 <- 33`

The best path will be
`1 -> 20 -> 33 -> 14 -> 1 -> 20 -> 5`
with sum `73`.

Comment: and what is the question and what have youi achieved so far?

Comment: @mikus The question is how can this be done in good time complexity. At the moment I'm completely clueless and I have no idea whatsoever how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Step one: eliminate all cycles. You can find a cycle by picking any node and doing a DFS from there. If you don't find a cycle find another node that you haven't visisted in the previous DFS and do a DFS from that node. If you find a cycle collapse all the nodes into a single one. Basically if you reach any of the nodes in the cycle, you will go through the cycle to get all the weights. Since you can reuse nodes and edges you will always be able to continue on your path as before. After you found a cycle repeat the algorithm, until you have collapsed all cycles.

Step two: find a path through the collapsed graph. Now there are no cycles, so you can use Bellman Ford and find the longest route (you need to change the conditions to look for longer paths instead of shorter). Because every collapsed node has the weigth of the cycle it represents you get the weight you are looking for. If you want to reconstruct the path then you also need to look at the cycles you collapsed and expand them in place, taking care to add the path from the input point to the exit point in the cycle (Say you have a cycle with 10 nodes, the input edge goes to node 1 but the exit edge goes from node 5, so you need to add the entire cycle 1,2,3,4,5.. 10 starting from the input edge and then add the part of the cycle that takes you to the exit edge, in this case 1,2,3,4,5).

Complexity is O(N^2). A DFS is O(N) (including picking other nodes in case you don't find from the current one) and every time you eliminate at least one node (you can't have a cycle with a single node) so you will run it at most N times. BellmanFord algorithm is also O(N^2). Reconstruction should be at most O(N).

Comment: Thank you very much. As weights are positive integers (I haven't mentioned that earlier), Dijkstra's algorithm can be used instead of BF, slightly reducing the complexity. I'm a bit scared by the `O(N^2)` - there may be as much as 200 000 vertices (and up to 1 000 000 edges) - I'm not sure this algorithm will meet time requirements.

Comment: I don't think you can use Dijkstra, because you're looking for the longest path (equivalent to all the weights are negative here). You can speed it up a bit by trying to collapse cycles faster. You can do this by running another DFS from one of the nodes in the cycle, but going backwards over the edges, then collapsing all the nodes that have been visited by both DFSs. Should ensure you maximize the number of nodes you collapse at once, but the complexity remains roughly the same.